# Error while starting peer with security and privacy turned on

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger

When I try to start the peer using

```
peer node start
```

I get the following error

```
hyperledger@linux-box:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ peer node start
20:42:02.999 [crypto] main -> INFO 001 Log level recognized 'info', set to INFO
20:42:03.017 [main] serve -> INFO 002 Security enabled status: true
20:42:03.017 [main] serve -> INFO 004 Privacy enabled status: true
20:42:03.017 [crypto] func1 -> INFO 005 Registering validator [vp] with name [vp]...
20:42:03.017 [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 003 event processor started
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x8ad221]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0xd43fe0, 0xc82000e120)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/utils.PEMtoPrivateKey(0x15409e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/utils/keys.go:117 +0x91
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto.(*nodeImpl).retrieveEnrollmentData(0xc820226630, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0xc8201c35f0, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/node_eca.go:120 +0xe55
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto.(*nodeImpl).registerCryptoEngine(0xc820226630, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0xc8201c35f0, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/node_crypto.go:49 +0x5d6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto.(*nodeImpl).register(0xc820226630, 0x2, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0xc8201c35f0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/node_impl.go:114 +0x5b8
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto.(*peerImpl).register(0xc820242840, 0x2, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0xc8201c35f0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/peer_impl.go:177 +0x20a
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto.(*validatorImpl).register(0xc8201fd600, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0xc8201c35f0, 0xc, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/validator_impl.go:147 +0x20a
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto.RegisterValidator(0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8201c35c8, 0x2, 0xc8201c35f0, 0xc, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/validator.go:55 +0x55d
main.getSecHelper.func1()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:360 +0x200
sync.(*Once).Do(0x1540ad8, 0xc8201fd768)
    /opt/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xe4
main.getSecHelper(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:380 +0x7d
main.serve(0x15409e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:446 +0xc23
main.glob.func3(0x1503160, 0x15409e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:95 +0x41
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1503160, 0x15409e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:497 +0x62c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x1502de0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:584 +0x46a
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:314 +0x18d9
```

My core.yaml contains the default contents , with security and privacy enabled.

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Not sure if your peer executable was compiled correctly. If you will try to run “make peer” in the fabric folder, the peer file will be created in “fabric/build/bin/”. Do you use this path to run Validation Peer ?

Comment: I am using the executables that were generated in the fabric/build/bin by the 'make peer' and 'make membersrvc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I still think the fact that we panic is a bug, but my guess is that you have not built and/or started membership services which are required when security is enabled:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/API/SandboxSetup.md#security-setup-optional

Edit:  I originally missed something in the stack trace above.  Looks like you are running on a very old version of the fabric code.  For example `github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/crypto/utils/keys.go` is no longer in the current code.  I checked out your fork and it seems you are still pretty far behind.  Not sure if you are building out of your fork or not, but looks like you definitely have old code and need to pull down upstream changes

Comment: Thanks :) . I had an old executable in my GOBIN that was causing the trouble.